# How is App Installs calculated in the Dynamic links panel

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

What is the relationship of Clicks, App-installs, Redirect, First-open, Re-open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`APP_INSTALL` is only logged when users installs the app from a Firebase Dynamic Link. This is only supported by the Play Store as mentioned in the [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics#analytics). This means installs from other platforms (mainly iOS App Store) won't get logged.

Having smaller `APP_INSTALL` count than `CLICK` makes sense since not all users who clicks on the Dynamic Link needs to install the app.

Edit: Added more details below.

`CLICK` is recorded when a user clicks the FDL and sends a request to the FDL server

`REDIRECT` is recorded when a successful response was given by the FDL server. The event may send the user to the App Store, fallback URL, or to the app receiving the link.

Here's how the flow looks

[image: fdl_analytics_chart]

However, it's a bit tricky on iOS when the app is installed and Universal Links is triggered. In this instance, no requests to FDL server will be made, therefore no FDL events `CLICK` and `REDIRECT` will be logged before `APP_RE_OPEN`.

Comment: Just a note on that documentation, it does not have check marks in the "Firebase Console" column for the redirect & app_install events.  This is definitely not the case, you CAN see them in the Firebase console.  I've submitted a report to about the inaccuracy of that doc.

Comment: It's in the document Omatt linked.  Redirects: "Count of attempts to redirect users, either to the App Store or Play Store to install or update the app, or to some other destination".
Usually, a redirect occurs when a user can't get to the App Store or Play Store, and you have specified the other platforms parameter (ofl) (doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually)

Comment: I've updated my response explaining when the events `CLICK` and `REDIRECT` are logged.

Comment: Thank you Omatt so much for your answer! One detail that is still quite confusing to me is that we only see a few redirects but a bunch of clicks and app-installs. According to your plot here, it seems to me like it should be: Clicks >= Redirect >= App-Install? However it is not what I see. What I see is Clicks > App-installs >> Redirects.

Comment: Do you mean that `APP_INSTALL` is higher than `REDIRECT`? I suggest reaching out to support to verify if there's any issues https://firebase.google.com/support

Comment: Yes, APP_INSTALL is much higher than REDIRECTS. Which category or channel do you recommend me to reach out to?